# How to acced to google object in vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vuejs2

I'm trying to use the google maps API at my vue2 project and I have tried some ways that have failed. After using the vue2googlemaps module and the node module from google I have decided to use the CDN directly and add it to the index page. My problem now is that to acced to the google object, for example, to create a Marker or something like that, I need to use `this.marker = new window.google.maps.Marker()` for example, but in the tutorials I have seen, everyone uses directly the google object and never uses that `window`. I can`t understand why it happens. It would be appreciated if someone shows me the correct way to import or use this library on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your template's code is compiled and executed in your component instance (a.k.a `vm`) 's scope, not in the global (a.k.a. `window`) scope.

To use `google` directly in your template you could add the following computed:

```js
computed: {
  google: () => window.google
}
```

---

If your problem is not having `google` defined in the component's `<script>`, a simple solution is to add it as a `const` at the top:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
const google = window.google;

export default Vue.extend({
  computed: {
    google: () => google // also make it available in template, as `google`
  }
})
```

---

An even more elegant solution is to teach webpack to get `google` from the window object whenever it's imported in any of your components:

`vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    externals: {
      google: 'window.google'
    }
  }
}
```

This creates a `google` namespace in your webpack configuration so you can import from it in any of your components:

```js
import google from 'google';

//... 
  computed: {
    google: () => google // provide it to template, as `google`
  }
```

Why do I say it's more elegant?
Because it decouples the component from the context and now you don't need to modify the component when used in different contexts (i.e: in a testing environment, which might not even use a browser, so it might not have a `window` object, but a `global` instead; all you'd have to do in this case is to define a `google` namespace in that environment and that's where your component will get its `google` object from; but you wouldn't have to tweak or mock any of the component's methods/properties).